# Images and Links in EXM message are not coming when receiving the e-mail

Tags: sitecore-forms, exm

I am working on Sitecore 10.3 and created automated message from EXM, I added custom html in Body Text component and added image and link from Sitecore media.
but when I sent the email,
[image]
, I received the e-mail without images and links, not coming in the correct way.
[image]

when I checked the src of image it came like that

> https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/meips/ADKq_NaMGesUffd5sBGiB_nbhufndys23P2XfY713Gnt4Qs3GWyIGoxar-CSyfQTccu7E6yqH4Azl4wu_jHRw8CxMx4qvyf21xtgwHlfFdUP-AR8pgTaee6NCcTEI7dmk4md8oyBWuKaNh9PoSR-c-o=s0-d-e1-ft#http://your.host/-/media/Project/Murabba/murabba-site/images/Email-Template/image_1.png

I do not know why it is coming like that, any idea how to resolve this??

Comment: is it your links : http://your.host/-/media/Project/Murabba/murabba-site/images/Email-Template/image_1.png  available outside of your network ?

Comment: the issue is my site domain not coming it replaces with "your.host" this not my site domain, I need to connect to vpn to access my site not public url but, I am connected to this vpn while receiving the e-mails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the "Base Url" Field in your "Email Configuration" in Content Tree
and change it to your domain

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the link to media file is wrong because your Email Root tenant is not configured.

Please have a
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/exm/103/email-experience-manager/edit-the-exm-default-settings.html

You have **your.host** because that is the default value. Have a look on below picture.

[image]